# Swift: .contains(where:) using key-path expression

Tags: swift, filter, functional-programming, contains, swift-keypath

Is there someway to use a key-path expression to simplify boilerplate code in a Swift `contains(where:`)?

E.g.

```swift
struct Struct {
  let bool: Bool
}
let structs = [
  Struct(bool: false), 
  Struct(bool: false),
  Struct(bool: true), 
  Struct(bool: false),
  Struct(bool: false)
]
let hasTruth = structs.contains { $0.bool }
print(hasTruth) // true
```

Is the above example possible to express in Swift, using `\.bool` on the `struct Struct`, without resorting to `structs.filter(\.bool).count > 0`?

Comment: ```structs.contains(where: \.bool)``` ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you simply need to pass the key-path to `contains(where:)` without a closure, same as you do with `filter`.

```
let hasTruth = structs.contains(where: \.bool)
```